# XSLT 3.0 Nested grouping and counting string values

Tags: xslt-2.0, nested-loops, counting, xslt-grouping, xslt-3.0

I have jobs and multiple job tests for which I have to get 'pass' and 'fail' count by gender.My current code is working if there is one jobtest for each job.If any job has multiple job tests the counts are incorrect.
Here is my fiddle with with xml and xslt code.job 1 counts are correct as it has only one test.Job 2 counts are incorrect as it has multiple jobtests.

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9GPfH/1

Expected Totals
Job,    job_Test,   Ma_Pass,    Ma_Fail,    Fem_Pass,   Fem_Fail
Job 1,  Application Evaluation, 5,  3,  9,  2
Job 2,  Application Evaluation, 304,    2,  131,    0
Job 2,  Suitability Test,   127,    118,    53, 54

Anyhelp is hightly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the nested `Job_Test` in the inner grouping:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:r="urn:com.workday.report/Test_by_Gender"
    xmlns:this="urn:this"
    xmlns:is="java:com.workday.esb.intsys.xpath.ParsedIntegrationSystemFunctions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">


     <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="r:Report_Data">


        <Root>

         <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xD;&#xA;'"/>

            <xsl:for-each-group select="r:Report_Entry" group-by="r:Job/@r:Descriptor">
                <xsl:variable name="entry" select="."/>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/r:Test_Result_group/r:Job_Test" group-by="@r:Descriptor">

                       <Job><xsl:value-of select = "$entry/r:Job/@r:Descriptor"/></Job>

                        <Job_Test><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></Job_Test>

                        <xsl:variable name="Females" select="current-group()[ancestor::r:Report_Entry/r:Gender = 'Female']"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="FemalePass" select="this:CountResultByStatus($Females,'Pass')"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="FemaleFail" select="this:CountResultByStatus($Females, 'Fail')"/>

                        <xsl:variable name="Males" select="current-group()[ancestor::r:Report_Entry/r:Gender = 'Male']"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="MalePass" select="this:CountResultByStatus($Males,'Pass')"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="MaleFail" select="this:CountResultByStatus($Males,'Fail')"/>

                         <Total_Male><xsl:value-of select="count($Males)"/></Total_Male>
                         <Male_Pass><xsl:value-of select= "$MalePass"/></Male_Pass>
                         <Male_Fail><xsl:value-of select= "$MaleFail"/></Male_Fail> 



                        <Total_Female><xsl:value-of select="count($Females)"/></Total_Female>
                        <Female_Pass><xsl:value-of select="$FemalePass"/> </Female_Pass>
                        <Female_Fail><xsl:value-of select="$FemaleFail"/></Female_Fail>


               <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/> 

               </xsl:for-each-group>

            </xsl:for-each-group>

          </Root>


    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="this:CountResultByStatus" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:param name="People" as="element()*"/>
        <xsl:param name="Status" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="count($People[../r:Test_Status = $Status])"/>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9GPfH/2

Comment: Any XSLT 2 examples would work the same with XSLT 3. Anyway, even if related to the same input set, try to ask a new question with minimal but representative samples of XML input, XSLT you have, XML result you want and the one you get, to allow us to understand the problem. Some samples of XSLT 3 based grouping are shown in the relevant section directly here on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Martin.Sure,will create a new question.